# XGBOOST verbose_eval in Jupyter not working

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-notebook, xgboost

I'm running the following in a python Jupyter notebook:

```
import xgboost as xgb
bst_dx=xgb.train(paramMap,dset,num_round,verbose_eval=True)
```

For some reason I never see the actual verbose evaluation, which is supposed to print the current loss at the last evaluated boost. I've tried setting verbose_eval to 1,2,3,4, etc but that still doesn't do anything. I just get a silent output. Is there some setting I need to enable in Jupyter?

Answer (score 2):

You also need to provide your evaluation data set/s and the number of rounds of no improvement after which you want to invoke an early stop. For example:

```
xgb_params = {"objective": "multi:softprob", "max_depth": 8, "silent": 1, "num_class":5}
num_rounds = 1000
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(trainX, trainY)    #training data
dvalid = xgb.DMatrix(validX, validY)    #validation data
thisxgb = xgb.train(xgb_params, dtrain, num_rounds, \
                    [(dtrain,'train'),(dvalid,'test')], \
                    early_stopping_rounds=10\
                   )    #stop if no improvement in 10 rounds
```